# select the max of averages with SQL

Tags: sql, database, select, sqlexception

I'm trying to get the max of averages by using this query :

```
select code, avg(note) 
from exam 
group by code 
having avg(note)=(select max(avg(note)) from exam group by code)
```

but I get this error :

```
Invalid use of group function
```

where I had wrong?

Comment: Tag your question with the database system you're using. "SQL" is a language used in many different ones.

Comment: I'm using mySQL database

Answer (score 1):

Nesting aggregation function at the same level will not work. Altenative approach is to order by avg descending and take first row:

```
SELECT code, avg(note) AS avg_note
FROM exam
GROUP BY code
ORDER BY avg_note DESC
LIMIT 1;
```